# How to build a simple pybind library with Bazel using a hermetic Python install

Tags: bazel, pybind11, bazel-rules

I am trying to set up a simple Bazel workspace to build a pybind library and I am unable to get Bazel to use a specific non-system python (pulled using the `rules_python` Bazel pakage).

This is my setup:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
└── example.cpp
```

BUILD:

```
load("@pybind11_bazel//:build_defs.bzl", "pybind_extension")

pybind_extension(
    name = "example",
    srcs = ["example.cpp"],
    deps = [ ],
)
```

WORKSPACE:

```
oad("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "8c8fe44ef0a9afc256d1e75ad5f448bb59b81aba149b8958f02f7b3a98f5d9b4",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.13.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/archive/refs/tags/0.13.0.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "python_register_toolchains")

python_register_toolchains(
    name = "python3_9",
    python_version = "3.9",
)

load("@python3_9//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

pip_parse(
    python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
)

http_archive(
  name = "pybind11_bazel",
  strip_prefix = "pybind11_bazel-9a24c33cbdc510fa60ab7f5ffb7d80ab89272799",
  urls = ["https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_bazel/archive/9a24c33cbdc510fa60ab7f5ffb7d80ab89272799.zip"],
)
http_archive(
  name = "pybind11",
  build_file = "@pybind11_bazel//:pybind11.BUILD",
  strip_prefix = "pybind11-2.10.0",
  urls = ["https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/archive/refs/tags/v2.10.0.zip"],
)
load("@pybind11_bazel//:python_configure.bzl", "python_configure")
python_configure(
  name = "local_config_python",
  python_interpreter_target = "**what goes here**",
)
```

example.cpp:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

void do_something() { }

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("do_something", &do_something, "A function that does something");
}
```

If I remove the `python_interpreter_target = "**what goes here**"` line from the `WORKSPACE` everything works, but it is using the system python which I am trying to avoid. But I can't find where/what bazel target the python3 binary is from the `rules_bazel` pakage pull.

In case it helps, these are all the targets I can see for `@python3_9`:

```
% bazel query @python3_9//... 
@python3_9//:files
@python3_9//:includes
@python3_9//:libpython
@python3_9//:pip
@python3_9//:py3_runtime
@python3_9//:python3
@python3_9//:python_headers
@python3_9//:python_runtimes
Loading: 0 packages loaded
```

(None of these seem to be what `python_interpreter_target` wants)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just need to pass in the interpreter:

```
load("@python3_9//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")
...
python_configure(
    name = "local_config_python",
    python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try passing the actual path to your target python executable. Kindly check the python executable into the third_party dir and instead of invoking your rules_python using simply python pass the relative path to that executable relative to WORKSPACE. Thank you!